# Add image to Azure Devops Dashboard

Tags: azure-devops, markdown

I need to add a static image to Azure Devops dashboard. Is the easiest way to do this using the MarkDown widget? 
And if so, where do I store my image to link to it in markdown? And can you please give me an example?
does the dashboard have a storage area for images, or markdown files? Or does it have to be stored somwhere in my git repository. I would prefer not to, as I am merely a scrummaster, with no easy access to git repository.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use a static image in your dashboard without storing the image a git repository, you can store it into your project wiki.

The trick is to:

1. Add an image to any wiki page
2. **Submit** your changes and **close the page editor**
3. **Right-click** on the image, and select the option **"Copy the image's address"**
4. Then, in your dashboard, add a MarkDown widget, in which you put the following content:

```
![Text](youre-image-url-address)
```

And that's it! :)
Beware of taking the image address after closing the wiki page editor, otherwise the link you'll get will be a blob and won't work.

Comment: Wow thanks that worked. Now to the more irritating questions.
I am not so happy to define a dummy page in the project wiki, as the developers will complain that I am poluting their wiki. Is there any way to hide the page?
Moreover, is there a way to access the image file and replace it with another, without having to create a new image link?
And is the wiki really the only place I can store an image for the dashboard? can I not create some hidden folder on devops to store it in?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Too many questions lol, each one would require some research and tests. Maybe ask them separately to the community, because I haven't found out how to make it work another way yet ^^'

Comment: fyi: the wiki article can be changed again after one has the link. The uploaded image is not coupled with any wiki article and it is not checked if the image is linked anywhere. It is still persisted and the link in the dashboard will work after deleting the image from the article or deleting the whole article.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to copy/paste an image to a Work Item description (or any other rich text field).  For example, copy paste an image into a work item's Description field. Then do one of the following:

1. **Easier**: Use your browser to get the image URL like you would any other image (Windows:Chrome = right-click).
2. **Advanced**: Save it. Capture the work item's Template and get the URL out the descriptions HTML.

*I even deleted the work item (permanently from Recycle Bin) and the link still worked. Of course, I wouldn't count on this because that sounds like a Bug to me.*